# Singular point of $f(z)=\bar{z}$

Tags: complex-analysis

We say that $a$ is a singular point of $f$ if it is not analytic at that point. $f(z)=\bar{z}$ is not analytic in whole $z$-plane. Does this means that every element in the complex plane is a singular point for $f$?

Comment: Yes, $f(z) = z^{*}$ is nowhere analytic. The Cauchy-Riemann equations are not satisfied for any $z\in\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: You must define "singular point" for the purpose you need.  When we say $z=a$ is a singular point of $f(z)$, we probably mean that $f$ is an analytic function everywhere in a neighborhood of $a$, but not at $a$ itself.  So I would not say that $\overline{z}$ is singular at every point.  I would say (As Tucker did) that $\overline{z}$ is analytic nowhere.

Comment: @GEdgar a definition is certainly useful. For this question $f(z)$ is nowhere differentiable.

Comment: Nowhere differentiable in the complex sense. It is way smoothier than most functions as a real function.